# Custom Route for GDirections Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to create a custom route for GDirections to walk around? Like it does for roads etc.

If I have 10 way points, and there is a building in the way, if I just walk from waypoint 1 to waypoint 2, it will walk straight through the building.

Is there a way to tell it to walk on a custom pre-defined route?

I was thinking maybe make use of KML or something?

Cheers, Sarkie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want a custom route, or do you want to the GDirections object to figure out its own route, ensuring that it avoids certain obstacles?

For the first method, just use more waypoints.

For the second, I have no idea. =(